# How to use Pulp to set up conditional statements and constraints in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, constraints, pulp

I'm trying to use Pulp to create a shift scheduling tool with various constraints on when an employee can work and how many of each shift they can work. An example of the input parameters are as follows:

Inputs:

- Total Staff= 8
- Special Staff = 4
- Days = 30
- Shifts = 7

Variables:

- shift_0 (day)
- shift_1 (day)
- shift_2 (special day)
- shift_3 (special night)
- shift_4 (night)
- shift_5 (optional night)
- shift_6 (vacation)

Constraints:

- A worker can only work one shift a day
- Shifts 0, 1, 4 must be filled everyday
- Special staff can't work more than 2 'Thursdays' (Days 3, 10, 17, 24)
- Each shift can only be filled by one person
- Each worker must work exactly 5 nights (shifts 4 or 5)
- All nights are scheduled consecutively (i.e., 5 days of nights in a row)
- No worker may work more than 12 days consecutively
- All night shift blocks must be preceded by a special night and followed by 2 days vacation

I have several constraints that I'm working through but the few that I'm primarily hung up on are that night shifts must be scheduled in consecutive days (5 at a time), a 'special night' shift has to precede a block of nights, and two vacation days must follow a block of nights.

I'm using conditional if-else statements to setup the problem but I'm not getting the constraint I expect when I look at the LP file. I get a 'Status Infeasible' error when executing the code. If I ignore the block in question then a solution is found.

Any suggestions on how I can better cast the constraints?

```
import pulp

number_of_staff = 8  #i
number_of_rotators = 4 #z
number_of_days = 28  #j
number_of_shifts = 7 #k Two day, one day admit, one PM admit, two night (one optional), one vacation (optional)

# Decision Variables
var_day0 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('day-0', (range(number_of_staff), range(number_of_days)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
var_day1 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('day-1', (range(number_of_staff), range(number_of_days)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
var_day_admit = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('day-admit', (range(number_of_staff), range(number_of_days)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
var_pm_admit = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('pm-admit', (range(number_of_staff), range(number_of_days)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
var_night0 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('night-0', (range(number_of_staff), range(number_of_days)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
var_night1 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('night-1', (range(number_of_staff), range(number_of_days)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
var_off = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('off', (range(number_of_staff), range(number_of_days)), 0, 1, 'Binary')

# Object function
obj = None
weekend_weight = 0

#Preference that all shifts are staffed
for i in range(number_of_staff):
    for j in range(number_of_days):
        obj += var_day0[i][j] + var_day1[i][j] + var_day_admit[i][j] + var_pm_admit[i][j] + var_night0[i][j]
    
    #Add bonus for consecutive weekend days off
    if var_off[i][5] == 1 and var_off[i][6] == 1:
        obj += weekend_weight
        
    if var_off[i][12] == 1 and var_off[i][13] == 1:
        obj += weekend_weight
        
    if var_off[i][19] == 1 and var_off[i][20] == 1:
        obj += weekend_weight
        
    if var_off[i][26] == 1 and var_off[i][27] == 1:
        obj += weekend_weight
        
problem = pulp.LpProblem('shift', pulp.LpMaximize)
problem += obj

# # Setting constraints

# Both day shifts must be filled, night shift must be filled
for j in range(number_of_days):
    c = None
    d = None
    e = None
    
    for i in range(number_of_staff):
        c += var_day0[i][j]
        d += var_day1[i][j]
        e += var_night0[i][j]
        
    problem += c == 1
    problem += d == 1
    problem += e == 1

# No more than one person on optional night
for j in range(number_of_days):
    c = None
    
    for i in range(number_of_staff):
        c += var_night1[i][j]
        
    problem += c <= 1
    
# Only one shift a day
for j in range(number_of_days):
    
    for i in range(number_of_staff):
        c = None
        c += var_day0[i][j] + var_day1[i][j] + var_day_admit[i][j] + var_pm_admit[i][j] + var_night0[i][j] + var_night1[i][j] + var_off[i][j]
        
        problem += c == 1
        
# Everyone must work 5 nights
for i in range(number_of_staff):
    c = None
    
    for j in range(number_of_days):
        c += var_night0[i][j] + var_night1[i][j]
        
    problem += c == 5
    
# No one can work more than 12 days in a row      
for i in range(number_of_staff):
    for j in range(0, number_of_days-13):
        c = None
        
        for w in range(j, j+12):
            c += var_day0[i][j] + var_day1[i][j] + var_day_admit[i][j] + var_pm_admit[i][j] + var_night0[i][j] + var_night1[i][j]
        
        problem += c <= 12
        
# Rotators no more than 2 thursdays of night or pm
for z in range(number_of_rotators):
    c = None
    for j in [3, 10, 17, 24]:
        c += var_night0[z][j] + var_night1[z][j] + var_pm_admit[z][j]
        
    problem += c <= 2
    
# All nights must be 5 consecutive shifts and must be preceded by a pm_admit and followed by two days off
##### PROBLEM SECTION BELOW #####
for i in range(number_of_staff):
    c = None
    d = None
    e = None
    
    for j in range(number_of_days):
             
        if var_night0[i][j] == 1 or var_night1[i][j] == 1:
            
            for w in range(5):
                c += var_night0[i][j+w] + var_night1[i][j+w]
            
            if j != 0:
                d += var_pm_admit[i][j-1]
            else:
                d = 1
                
            if j < 23:
                e += var_off[i][j+5] + var_off[i][j+6]
            else:
                e = 2
            
            break
            
    problem += c == 5
    problem += d == 1
    problem += e == 2

# Solve problem
status = problem.solve()

# If optimal print 'Optimal solution found'
problem.writeLP('lpfile')

print('Status', pulp.LpStatus[status])
```

Comment: `if var_off[i][5] == 1` does not do what you think it does. The fundamentals of LP require that this be entered in an affine expression.

Answer (score 1):

Good news / bad news here.... :)

Your question is interesting and you included your code and a working example, which is a great way to ask a question.

The problem you describe is significantly more complicated than you think.  Mainly because I think you have some mistaken understanding of some fundamental principles of LP.  You cannot use "if" (or conditional) statements in the formulation of the LP.  You are doing that in both your objective statement (as noted in the comment) and you are *thinking* of doing it in the constraints that you want.  Realize that the value of the variables is unknown when the problem is formulated (that is the solver's job) so those `if` statements are not going to work.  If you start off with a **tiny** version of your model and print out the objective statement, you'll see some of those issues.

Also, you are going to cause problems with your staff indexing.  You have overlaps between the regular folks and the rotating staff.  If I "assign" in a variable such as `var_day0[2, 3]`  is that regular staff member #2 or rotating staff member #2 ????  You need to de-conflict those things.

Last nit-pick before the good news...  I'm not sure why you are building your expressions as you are.  You should just be using `sum()` as I do below.

You have many of the right concepts here, but some of your constraints are quite complicated.  Specifically, things like "work 5 nights in a row".  I use an extra variable to indicate when that sequence starts and some "creative" constraints to look for that indicator variable.

Also, 2 side notes...  If you tinker with your model much, it may become infeasible, so be careful.  For example, as you require everybody to do 1 night sequence, you have 8 workers * 5 day sequence = 40 night slots that must be filled.  You have 27 "night_4" slots that *must* be filled and a maximum of 54 night_4 + night_5 slots, so if you go up or down much on the staff numbers, it becomes infeasible real quick.  Second, if you are developing something like this (or working with the below model), chop the data down to something **extremely small** and print the model out a bunch of times (I left some remnants) to ensure the math matches the plan.

I found the problem interesting, so I reworked it....  The below runs and I'm pretty sure is accurate.

##### Code:

```
import pulp
import sys

###  DATA

regular_staff  = {'bob', 'sally', 'john', 'tim', 'donny', 'mick'}
rotating_staff = {'tom', 'judy'}
all_staff = regular_staff | rotating_staff
days = list(range(30))   # <-- keep it SMALL till it works, I started with 4 days
shifts       = {'day_0', 'day_1', 'day_2_special', 'night_3_special', 'night_4', 'night_5'}
night_shifts = {'night_4', 'night_5'}
night_block_length  = 5
post_night_days_off = 2
max_consecutive     = 12


### VARS
shift_idx = [(staff, day, shift) for staff in all_staff for day in days for shift in shifts]
night_shift_days = days[1: len(days) + 1  - night_block_length - post_night_days_off]
night_shift_idx = [(staff, day) for staff in all_staff for day in night_shift_days]
# print(night_shift_idx)

# assignment to for staff member to work day / shift...
work = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('work', shift_idx, cat=pulp.LpBinary )  # upper/lower bounds are implied for binary
# an indicator for what night the night block is started on...
night_block_start = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('start_night',night_shift_idx, cat=pulp.LpBinary)

prob = pulp.LpProblem('shift', pulp.LpMaximize)

### OBJ

# not clear what your overall objective is, so let's maximize shift execution...
prob += sum(work[idx] for idx in shift_idx)

# print(prob)
# sys.exit(-1)

### CONSTRAINTS

# 1.  no double-filling shifts, but it can be unfilled...
for shift in shifts:
    for day in days:
        prob += sum(work[staff, day, shift] for staff in all_staff) <= 1

# 2.  no double shifts
for day in days:
    for staff in all_staff:
        prob += sum(work[staff, day, shift] for shift in shifts) <= 1

# 3.  must fills...
mandatory_fill_shifts = {'day_0', 'day_1', 'night_4'}
for shift in mandatory_fill_shifts:
    for day in days:
        # cannot fill day 0 night due to lack of ability to do the required shift prior...
        # cannot fill last days because of vacation requirement
        if (day == 0 or day >= len(days) - post_night_days_off) and shift == 'night_4':
            continue
        prob += sum(work[staff, day, shift] for staff in all_staff) >= 1

# things "in a row" need to reference prior time periods, which require some
# jiggering with the day indices
# 4.  nobody works more than x days in a row... implies all groups of x+1 days, only x assignments
for eval_day in days[:len(days) - max_consecutive]:
    for staff in all_staff: 
        prob += sum(work[staff, day, shift] 
            for day in range(eval_day, eval_day + max_consecutive + 1)  # the block of x+1 days
            for shift in shifts) <= max_consecutive
# print(prob)
# sys.exit(-1)

# 5.  must work a night_3_special on day before starting a night block
for day in night_shift_days:  # <- note, we are using a subset here of legal days to start the night sequence on
    for staff in all_staff:
        prob += night_block_start[staff, day] <= work[staff, day-1, 'night_3_special']

# 6.  starting night block implies mandatory assignment for next "night block length" days
for eval_day in days:
    # this vvvv is ugly.  had to tinker to get this windowing correct.  Could have done it with sets or such, but it works.
    lookback_window = days[max(1, eval_day - (night_block_length -1)) : min(max(night_shift_days), eval_day) +1]  # the block to look for a start signal
    print(f'lookback window check for night start:  on day {eval_day} window is {lookback_window}')
    for staff in all_staff:
        if not lookback_window:  # cannot be filled
            prob += sum(work[staff, eval_day, shift] for shift in night_shifts) <= 0
        else: 
            prob += sum(work[staff, eval_day, shift] for shift in night_shifts) == \
                sum(night_block_start[staff, day] for day in lookback_window)

# 7.  mandatory vacation block after night block
for day in night_shift_days:
    vaca_days = range(day + night_block_length, day + night_block_length + post_night_days_off)
    for staff in all_staff:
        prob += sum(work[staff, day, shift] 
            for shift in shifts for day in vaca_days) <= post_night_days_off * (1 - night_block_start[staff, day])

# 8.  special staff Thursday limit
special_days = [3, 10, 17, 24]
for day in special_days:
    for staff in rotating_staff:
        prob += sum(work[staff, day, shift] for shift in shifts) <= 2

# 9.  everybody does one (and only one) night stint
for staff in all_staff:
    prob += sum(night_block_start[staff, day] for day in night_shift_days) <= 1


# print(prob)
# sys.exit(-1)

# Solve problem
results = prob.solve()
status = pulp.LpStatus[results]
if status != 'Optimal':
    print(f'Status: {status}')
    sys.exit(-1)

print(f'Status:  {status}')

for t in sorted(shift_idx):
    if work[t].varValue:
        print(f'assign {t}')

for staff, day in sorted(night_shift_idx):
    if night_block_start[staff, day].varValue:
        print(f'start {staff} on night {day}')
```

##### Output (truncated):

```
   Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                160.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.33
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.34

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.34   (Wallclock seconds):       0.36

Status:  Optimal
assign ('bob', 0, 'night_3_special')
assign ('bob', 1, 'night_4')
assign ('bob', 2, 'night_5')
assign ('bob', 3, 'night_5')
assign ('bob', 4, 'night_5')
assign ('bob', 5, 'night_4')
assign ('bob', 9, 'day_0')
assign ('bob', 10, 'night_3_special')
assign ('bob', 11, 'day_1')
assign ('bob', 13, 'day_2_special')
assign ('bob', 14, 'day_0')
assign ('bob', 16, 'day_0')
assign ('bob', 17, 'day_0')
assign ('bob', 19, 'night_3_special')
assign ('bob', 20, 'day_2_special')
assign ('bob', 26, 'night_3_special')
assign ('bob', 27, 'night_3_special')
assign ('bob', 28, 'day_1')
assign ('donny', 0, 'day_2_special')
assign ('donny', 1, 'day_1')
assign ('donny', 2, 'night_3_special')
assign ('donny', 4, 'night_3_special')
assign ('donny', 5, 'day_2_special')
assign ('donny', 6, 'day_0')
assign ('donny', 7, 'night_3_special')
assign ('donny', 8, 'night_3_special')
assign ('donny', 10, 'day_2_special')
assign ('donny', 11, 'day_0')
assign ('donny', 12, 'day_1')
assign ('donny', 15, 'day_1')
assign ('donny', 17, 'day_1')
assign ('donny', 18, 'day_1')
assign ('donny', 19, 'day_2_special')
assign ('donny', 20, 'night_3_special')
assign ('donny', 21, 'night_4')
assign ('donny', 22, 'night_4')
assign ('donny', 23, 'night_5')
assign ('donny', 24, 'night_5')
assign ('donny', 25, 'night_5')
assign ('donny', 29, 'day_2_special')
assign ('john', 0, 'day_0')
assign ('john', 1, 'day_0')
assign ('john', 2, 'day_2_special')
assign ('john', 3, 'day_2_special')
assign ('john', 4, 'day_0')
assign ('john', 6, 'day_2_special')
assign ('john', 7, 'day_1')
assign ('john', 9, 'day_2_special')
assign ('john', 10, 'day_1')
assign ('john', 12, 'day_2_special')
assign ('john', 13, 'day_1')
assign ('john', 14, 'day_1')
assign ('john', 16, 'night_3_special')
assign ('john', 17, 'night_4')
assign ('john', 18, 'night_4')
assign ('john', 19, 'night_4')
assign ('john', 20, 'night_4')
assign ('john', 21, 'night_5')
assign ('john', 24, 'day_1')
assign ('john', 25, 'night_3_special')
assign ('john', 26, 'day_2_special')
assign ('john', 28, 'night_3_special')
assign ('john', 29, 'day_0')
assign ('judy', 2, 'day_0')
assign ('judy', 3, 'day_0')
assign ('judy', 5, 'night_3_special')
assign ('judy', 6, 'night_3_special')
assign ('judy', 7, 'night_4')
assign ('judy', 8, 'night_4')
assign ('judy', 9, 'night_4')
assign ('judy', 10, 'night_4')
assign ('judy', 11, 'night_4')
assign ('judy', 14, 'day_2_special')
assign ('judy', 15, 'day_2_special')
assign ('judy', 16, 'day_2_special')
assign ('judy', 18, 'night_3_special')
assign ('judy', 23, 'day_0')
assign ('judy', 24, 'night_3_special')
assign ('judy', 25, 'day_2_special')
assign ('judy', 27, 'day_2_special')
assign ('mick', 3, 'night_3_special')
assign ('mick', 4, 'day_1')
assign ('mick', 7, 'day_0')
assign ('mick', 8, 'day_2_special')
assign ('mick', 11, 'day_2_special')
assign ('mick', 12, 'day_0')
assign ('mick', 13, 'night_3_special')
assign ('mick', 14, 'night_5')
assign ('mick', 15, 'night_5')
assign ('mick', 16, 'night_5')
assign ('mick', 17, 'night_5')
assign ('mick', 18, 'night_5')
assign ('mick', 21, 'day_0')
assign ('mick', 22, 'day_1')
assign ('mick', 23, 'day_1')
assign ('mick', 25, 'day_0')
assign ('mick', 29, 'night_3_special')
assign ('sally', 1, 'day_2_special')
assign ('sally', 2, 'day_1')
assign ('sally', 5, 'day_1')
assign ('sally', 7, 'day_2_special')
assign ('sally', 8, 'day_0')
assign ('sally', 9, 'night_3_special')
assign ('sally', 10, 'day_0')
assign ('sally', 12, 'night_3_special')
assign ('sally', 13, 'day_0')
assign ('sally', 14, 'night_3_special')
assign ('sally', 15, 'night_3_special')
assign ('sally', 16, 'day_1')
assign ('sally', 17, 'night_3_special')
assign ('sally', 18, 'day_2_special')
assign ('sally', 19, 'day_0')
assign ('sally', 21, 'day_2_special')
assign ('sally', 22, 'night_3_special')
assign ('sally', 23, 'night_4')
assign ('sally', 24, 'night_4')
assign ('sally', 25, 'night_4')
assign ('sally', 26, 'night_4')
assign ('sally', 27, 'night_4')
assign ('tim', 0, 'day_1')
assign ('tim', 3, 'day_1')
assign ('tim', 4, 'day_2_special')
assign ('tim', 5, 'day_0')
assign ('tim', 6, 'day_1')
assign ('tim', 8, 'day_1')
assign ('tim', 11, 'night_3_special')
assign ('tim', 12, 'night_4')
assign ('tim', 13, 'night_4')
assign ('tim', 14, 'night_4')
assign ('tim', 15, 'night_4')
assign ('tim', 16, 'night_4')
assign ('tim', 20, 'day_1')
assign ('tim', 21, 'day_1')
assign ('tim', 22, 'day_2_special')
assign ('tim', 23, 'day_2_special')
assign ('tim', 24, 'day_0')
assign ('tim', 26, 'day_1')
assign ('tim', 27, 'day_0')
assign ('tim', 28, 'day_2_special')
assign ('tim', 29, 'day_1')
assign ('tom', 1, 'night_3_special')
assign ('tom', 2, 'night_4')
assign ('tom', 3, 'night_4')
assign ('tom', 4, 'night_4')
assign ('tom', 5, 'night_5')
assign ('tom', 6, 'night_4')
assign ('tom', 9, 'day_1')
assign ('tom', 15, 'day_0')
assign ('tom', 17, 'day_2_special')
assign ('tom', 18, 'day_0')
assign ('tom', 19, 'day_1')
assign ('tom', 20, 'day_0')
assign ('tom', 21, 'night_3_special')
assign ('tom', 22, 'day_0')
assign ('tom', 23, 'night_3_special')
assign ('tom', 24, 'day_2_special')
assign ('tom', 25, 'day_1')
assign ('tom', 26, 'day_0')
assign ('tom', 27, 'day_1')
assign ('tom', 28, 'day_0')
start bob on night 1
start donny on night 21
start john on night 17
start judy on night 7
start mick on night 14
start sally on night 23
start tim on night 12
start tom on night 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment AirSquid. I'm digesting your comments now. Will post back once I look through the changes.

Comment: got it.  Just looked at this again and realized that I accidentally made constraint #9 an inequality instead of an equality.  It still solves if you change it, but I think the way it is is actually better ... prevents some infeasibility if your staff numbers grow and the objective still fills as many spots as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering, I was able to resolve my issue by switching the 'night' variable to only be 1 on the first night shift of the 5 day block. It made the other constraints a bit more clunky as result, but it does linearize the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).