# How to correctly define minimum constraint for a shift automation software

Tags: python, automation, linear-programming, pulp

I wanted to create a LP problem for assigning shifts to workers using PuLP and Python. At first, there were no problems since I defined minimum required constraint (the total shifts worked in a week per shift). However, when I try to assign this constraint based on the sales data, the program does not perform as it should.

I calculated the sales data and gave the three shifts percentages based on the total sales and the sales in that shift. Now I wanted to split the workers based on that percentages, but when I try to do so, the program does not assign 2 days back to back holidays to the workers. It was able to assign them before I made the minimum constraint change. Here is the code, and the problematic parts are "Constraint 2" and  "Definition of minimum weekly worker variables".

```
import json
import pulp

days = 7  # One week (7 days)
employees = 200  # Replace with the actual number of employees
jsonWorkers = json.load(open("shiftData.json"))
eleman_8_16 = jsonWorkers["eleman_8_16"]
eleman_16_24 = jsonWorkers["eleman_16_24"]
eleman_24_8 = jsonWorkers["eleman_24_8"]

# Definition of minimum weekly worker variables
max_8_16 = round(eleman_8_16 * 5 * 200) + 10
max_16_24 = round(eleman_16_24 * 5 * 200) + 10
max_24_8 = round(eleman_24_8 * 5 * 200) + 10
min_8_16 = round(eleman_8_16 * 5 * 200) - 10
min_16_24 = round(eleman_16_24 * 5 * 200) - 10
min_24_8 = round(eleman_24_8 * 5 * 200) - 10


var_8_16 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("8_16", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
var_16_24 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("16_24", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
var_24_8 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("24_8", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
var_Tatil = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Tatil", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
obj = None

for i in range(days):
    for j in range(employees):
        obj += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i][j] + var_24_8[i][j]  
problem = pulp.LpProblem("Vardiya", pulp.LpMaximize)
problem += obj

# Constraint 1: Each employee can only work one shift per day
for i in range(days):
    for j in range(employees):
        c = None
        c += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i][j] + var_24_8[i][j] + var_Tatil[i][j]
        problem += c == 1

# Constraint 2: Each shift must have at least c, d, f employees
for i in range(0, days):
    c = None
    d = None
    f = None
    for j in range(employees):
        c += var_8_16[i][j]
        d += var_16_24[i][j]
        f += var_24_8[i][j]
    problem += c >= min_8_16
    problem += c <= max_8_16
    problem += d >= min_16_24
    problem += d <= max_16_24
    problem += f >= min_24_8
    problem += f <= max_24_8

# Constraint 4: Each employee should work at most 5 days per week.
max_consecutive_days = 5
for j in range(employees):
    for i in range(0, days-6):
        c = None
        for w in range(7):
            c += var_8_16[i+w][j] + var_16_24[i+w][j] + var_24_8[i+w][j]
        problem += c <= max_consecutive_days

# Constraint 5: Each employee has to have two consecutive days off
for j in range(employees):
    for i in range(0, days-2):
        c = None
       c += var_Tatil[i][j] - var_Tatil[i+1][j] + var_Tatil[i+2][j]
        problem += c >= 0

# Constraint 6: Each employee should work same shift the next day.
for j in range(employees):
    for i in range(days - 1):
        c = None
        d = None
        f = None
        c += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i + 1][j] + var_24_8[i + 1][j]
        d += var_16_24[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 1][j] + var_24_8[i + 1][j]
        f += var_24_8[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 1][j] + var_16_24[i + 1][j]
        problem += c <= 1
        problem += d <= 1
        problem += f <= 1
    for i in range(days - 3):
        a = None
        b = None
        k = None
        a += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i + 3][j] + var_24_8[i + 3][j]
        b += var_16_24[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 3][j] + var_24_8[i + 3][j]
        k += var_24_8[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 3][j] + var_16_24[i + 3][j]
        problem += a <= 1
       problem += b <= 1
        problem += k <= 1
```

I am guessing that I calculate min and max variables wrong. There might not be enough workers for the constraints (min and max) to work, so that is why back to back holidays does not work. If that is the problem, how can I calculate the min and max so that I can divide 200 workers based on the percentages while considering one worker can work at most 5 shifts and each worker has 2 back to back holidays?

How can I solve this problem and correctly divide the workers based on the populousness of the shifts?

At first, only defined the "max_x_y" values for shifts and defined c, d, and f as:
`problem = c <= max_x_y`
However, the splitting was not so good. It was not based on the percentages. The one with 0.5 weight had 75 percent of the workers etc.

Later, I tried "min_x_y" and "max_x_y" with "-+ 1", but after it did not work, to give program more space to calculate, I change them to "-+10". But this also did not work.

Comment: in your constraint #6, do you mean that the employee *always* works the same shift?  You said "the next day".  How could it ever change?  After days off or never?

Comment: you should also try a "truth table" on Constraint #5, I don't think the logic is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made several mods here....  I think this will get you on the right track.  The only major issue I saw was that in constraint #1 you had an equality constraint, forcing at least 1 shift per day.  It should be a LTE (<=) constraint, for "at most" one shift per day to work with the vacation stuff.

You *could* write this a bit more clearly if you indexed the shifts rather than making new variable names, but for 3 shifts, it is OK.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76343586/how-to-use-pulp-to-set-up-conditional-statements-and-constraints-in-python/76344980#76344980) for an idea of how you might do this.

You can try to flip this and make it a minimization problem by switching the sense and see that this works for minimal assignments too.

##### Code:

```
import json
import pulp

days = 7  # One week (7 days)
num_employees = 10
employees = [f'e{i}' for i in range(num_employees)] # 200  # Replace with the actual number of employees
# jsonWorkers = json.load(open("shiftData.json"))
# eleman_8_16 = jsonWorkers["eleman_8_16"]
# eleman_16_24 = jsonWorkers["eleman_16_24"]
# eleman_24_8 = jsonWorkers["eleman_24_8"]

# Definition of minimum weekly worker variables
max_8_16  =  30    #round(eleman_8_16 * 5 * 200) + 10
max_16_24 =  20    #round(eleman_16_24 * 5 * 200) + 10
max_24_8  =  10    #round(eleman_24_8 * 5 * 200) + 10
min_8_16  =  3    #round(eleman_8_16 * 5 * 200) - 10
min_16_24 =  2     #round(eleman_16_24 * 5 * 200) - 10
min_24_8  =  1     #round(eleman_24_8 * 5 * 200) - 10


var_8_16  = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("8_16", (range(days), employees), cat="Binary")
var_16_24 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("16_24", (range(days), employees), cat="Binary")
var_24_8  = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("24_8", (range(days), employees), cat="Binary")
var_Tatil = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Tatil", (range(days), employees), cat="Binary")
first_day_off = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("first_day_off", (range(days-1), employees), cat="Binary")
obj = None

for i in range(days):
    for j in employees:
        obj += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i][j] + var_24_8[i][j]  
problem = pulp.LpProblem("Vardiya", pulp.LpMaximize)
problem += obj

# Constraint 1: Each employee can only work one shift per day
for i in range(days):
    for j in employees:
        c = None
        c += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i][j] + var_24_8[i][j] + var_Tatil[i][j]
        problem += c <= 1    # this should be <= constraint!  Risks infeasibility if equality (==)

# Constraint 2: Each shift must have at least c, d, f employees
for i in range(0, days):
    c = None
    d = None
    f = None
    for j in employees:
        c += var_8_16[i][j]
        d += var_16_24[i][j]
        f += var_24_8[i][j]
    problem += c >= min_8_16
    problem += c <= max_8_16
    problem += d >= min_16_24
    problem += d <= max_16_24
    problem += f >= min_24_8
    problem += f <= max_24_8

# Constraint 4: Each employee should work at most 5 days per week.
# max_total_days = 5    # this is TOTAL days, not consecutive
# for j in employees:
#     problem += sum(var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i][j] + var_24_8[i][j] for i in range(days)) <= 5


# Constraint 5a: Each employee has to start a 2-day off segment
for j in employees:
    problem += sum(first_day_off[i][j] for i in range(days-1)) == 1


# Constraint 5b: Each employee has to have two consecutive days off
for j in employees:
    for i in range(0, days-1):
        problem += var_8_16[i][j]   + var_16_24[i][j]   + var_24_8[i][j] + \
                   var_8_16[i+1][j] + var_16_24[i+1][j] + var_24_8[i+1][j] \
                   <= (1 - first_day_off[i][j]) * 2


# Constraint 6: Each employee should work same shift the next day.
for j in employees:
    for i in range(days - 1):
        c = None
        d = None
        f = None
        c += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i + 1][j] + var_24_8[i + 1][j]
        d += var_16_24[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 1][j] + var_24_8[i + 1][j]
        f += var_24_8[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 1][j] + var_16_24[i + 1][j]
        problem += c <= 1
        problem += d <= 1
        problem += f <= 1
    for i in range(days - 3):
        a = None
        b = None
        k = None
        a += var_8_16[i][j] + var_16_24[i + 3][j] + var_24_8[i + 3][j]
        b += var_16_24[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 3][j] + var_24_8[i + 3][j]
        k += var_24_8[i][j] + var_8_16[i + 3][j] + var_16_24[i + 3][j]
        problem += a <= 1
        problem += b <= 1
        problem += k <= 1

problem.solve()
for employee in employees:
    print(f'employee: {employee}')
    for d in range(days):
        print(f'  {d}: ', end='')
        if var_8_16[d][employee].varValue : print('8-16')
        elif var_16_24[d][employee].varValue : print('16-24')
        elif var_24_8[d][employee].varValue : print('24-8')
        else: print('--')
```

##### Output:

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                50.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.08
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.08

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.08   (Wallclock seconds):       0.09

employee: e0
  0: 24-8
  1: 24-8
  2: 24-8
  3: --
  4: --
  5: 24-8
  6: 24-8
employee: e1
  0: --
  1: --
  2: 8-16
  3: 8-16
  4: 8-16
  5: 8-16
  6: 8-16
employee: e2
  0: 16-24
  1: 16-24
  2: 16-24
  3: 16-24
  4: --
  5: --
  6: 16-24
employee: e3
  0: 8-16
  1: 8-16
  2: 8-16
  3: 8-16
  4: 8-16
  5: --
  6: --
employee: e4
  0: 24-8
  1: 24-8
  2: 24-8
  3: 24-8
  4: 24-8
  5: --
  6: --
employee: e5
  0: --
  1: --
  2: 16-24
  3: 16-24
  4: 16-24
  5: 16-24
  6: 16-24
employee: e6
  0: 8-16
  1: 8-16
  2: 8-16
  3: --
  4: --
  5: 8-16
  6: 8-16
employee: e7
  0: 16-24
  1: 16-24
  2: --
  3: --
  4: 16-24
  5: 16-24
  6: 16-24
employee: e8
  0: --
  1: --
  2: 8-16
  3: 8-16
  4: 8-16
  5: 8-16
  6: 8-16
employee: e9
  0: 8-16
  1: 8-16
  2: 8-16
  3: --
  4: --
  5: 8-16
  6: 8-16
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the modification!! I will now try the other methods you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: @Parristaba Great.  If this answered your question, it is customary to close out the issue by hitting the check mark next to the answer.